# "I haven't seen you the whole year" vs "for the whole year"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions

What are the grammar rules for using *all/the whole* in reference to time?

For example in the sentence,

> I haven't seen you the whole year
>   I haven't seen you **for** the whole year

My question is whether there should be FOR  or not.

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm afraid neither sentence makes much sense to me. Have you considerred the simpler "I haven't seen you all year".

Saying you haven't seen them for the whole year seems to imply an entire year has passed, and I just think there are too many words.

Here is a definition for the whole of something, as you can see I don't think that will ever apply when referring to the current year. If referring to the whole of the current year it would actually not be the whole of last year, as it would have had to already have transpired.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/license/amp/dictionary/the-whole-of-something

The same weird dictionary lists

> all
>
> determiner, predeterminer, pronoun
>
> 1 the whole of an amount, thing, or type of thing
>
> Have you done all your homework?
>   all your life/all day/all year etc (during the whole of your life, a day, a year etc)
>
> He had worked all his life in the mine.
>
> The boys played video games all day.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/all

Here's an article about removing filler words that might help.

https://www.autocrit.com/editing/support/unnecessary-filler-words/